# How to make link underline the same height

Tags: css, hover, transition, linear-gradients

I have links that have a hover styling:

```css
a {
  background-image: linear-gradient(currentColor, currentColor);
  background-position: 0% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 0% .05rem;
  transition: background-size .3s;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  background-size: 100% .05rem;
  color: inherit
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="">
      <span>Link1</span>
      <span class="dropdown-sign" title="" aria-hidden="true"><svg></svg></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href=""><span>Cuboro</span></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><span>Kaden</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This works fine EXCEPT for my submenu links. For some reason, certain submenu links have a thicker underlining than the rest in Firefox. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I have also tried sizing the background in pixels but even with 1px the lines have a different height. I played around with all different sizes and it changes which menu items have the thicker underline, but there always seem to be some that have it.

I can't figure out why - how can I make all underlines the same height?

Comment: add html please.

Comment: I did add the html.

Comment: @BSMP I have noticed that the issue only is on Firefox!

Comment: You're right, I cast the last re-open vote.